# Switch diagram, do not know what it means, or what it represents

Tags: switches

A neighbour asked me if I knew what these electrical switch symbols meant, or at least what they were so he could find out more:

[image: Image of Switch]

Comment: they mean absolutely zilch because they look like semi random scrawls on a piece of paper.

Comment: Those aren't schematic symbols.  They are what is commonly referred to as a "mess".  Show the original schematic your neighbor is asking about.

Comment: what a way to welcome someone to the community..... well done.

Comment: @MarkWalker (1)The Rottweilers are fast out of the gate today. (2) First symbol is perhaps meant to be a momentary action push button switch. Push button to make contact between two conductors. Second symbol is perhaps a sPST = single pole single throw switch - turn on/ turn off latching. (3) Take the useful content from the Rottweilers and ignore the aggro & you'll find that there is useful advice. It's unlikely that the symbol shown are what your neighbour actually saw anywhere. Drawing them more tidily would have been trivially easy and would have done your neighbour and yourself a favor.

Comment: Have a look at these [switch symbols](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=spst+symbol&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=tkh7U9iiMounkAXvp4C4Dg&ved=0CCgQsAQ&biw=1920&bih=1075) - each links to a webpage. Many are for SPST latch on - latch off switches. | Here are [pushbutton symbols](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=spst+symbol&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=tkh7U9iiMounkAXvp4C4Dg&ved=0CCgQsAQ&biw=1920&bih=1075#q=pushbutton+symbol+momentary&tbm=isch). Are these what you were trying to convey?

Comment: @MarkWalker I'm in NZ. You may wish to say hello by email. See my profile page for email address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few variations of "standard" switch symbols used in schematics. For example, the most basic single-pole, single-throw (SPST) switch:

[image: SPST Switch]

And the push-button version of the same thing:

[image: SPST Push-button]

The drawing you have sort of looks like a mix of these two, or perhaps a single-pole, double-throw (SPDT) switch with a sort of chopped-off right side of the drawing:

[image: SPDT Switch]

It would help to know what context the drawing you have is used in. They could be a proprietary symbol used in a specific industry or area of electrical work, but just as likely badly-drawn or misremembered symbols.

Comment: Since it's a switch diaphragm, your pushbutton symbol is the correct one to use. The difference is that, instead of a button, the switch is activated when enough pressure is applied to force a diaphragm which is normally convex away from the contacts to "pop" into being convex in the other direction.

Comment: thanks for your help! to be honest I'm uncertain as to the context and see plainly how that could help. I'll print this page out for him and have a chat, thanks for your time, much appreciated.